# How to find the inverse of a multivariable function in terms of a single variable?

Tags: number-theory, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have the function $$T_{A,B}(x,y) = \frac{3}{\pi^2}(\frac{B_1}{y(A_1y-B_1x)},...,\frac{B_{v-1}}{y(A_{v-1}y-B_{v-1}x)})$$
for $A = (A_1,...,A_{ν−1}), B = (B_1,...,B_{ν−1}) \in \mathbb{Z}_+^{ν−1} = \{1,2,3,...\}$

For now, I will consider the case of $v=2$. Then, we get$$T_{A,B}(x,y) = \frac{3}{\pi^2}(\frac{B}{y(Ay-Bx)})$$ for positive integers $A,B$.

This being said, I need to find the inverse, in terms of some interval $I:= (0, \alpha$). That is, $$T_{A,B}^{-1}(\alpha)$$

Can this be done? I'm not so sure how I can find this inverse, nor comprehend what the inverse here would mean. The Research Paper I'm reading uses $T_{A,B}^{-1}(\alpha)$ for a theorem, but I'm not sure how to strictly define it. Any help would be appreciated.